# Where to put Kotlin files in a new Android project using mostly Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am starting a new Android project for a client. The previous projects were all in Java and we decided to make the jump to Kotlin. On the developer.android.com site I read that it's best to place Kotlin files in `src/main/kotlin`. However, when I create a new activity, it places my files in `src/main/java/<package>`. Also, when I want to organize my folder structure in `src/main/kotlin` I run into issues because right-clicking does not give me the option to create subdirectories. Of course, I can do this in Finder but it seems I am fighting the system. Can someone tell me what the best practice is in terms of Kotlin code organization? I had a hard time finding the answer on Google.

Comment: I've always just added it to the Java directory.  While its possible there's some subtle build system difference it seems to work just fine.  The only argument I can see for not is that you might be surprised by the language when you open the file.

Comment: If you want to go full Kotlin, can't you just use built in migrate to Kotlin and let the app be Kotlin instead of fighting the system. To me it would be easier to just migrate and let the system build everything instead of you trying to figure it out

Comment: Also when I migrate all my Java to Kotlin the migrate feature retains all my folder structures.. I may have to make Minor tweaks to code but it's faster

Comment: I use the `java` directory because it's really annoying to have Java and Kotlin code in separate directories when you're browsing code. And it makes the project structure the same as almost every other project out there. Kotlin documentation also recommends omitting the base package name directories, but I've never seen that done by anybody in practice (from browsing many public Github projects).

Comment: @Tenfour04 Good point. I did notice that the Kotlin documentation recommends omitting the base package name. I also had a hard time finding examples of that in the wild. I will stick everything in the Java directory under the package directory!

Comment: @CampNerd The project is full kotlin. I'm not using any Java code. But Android Studio is still placing my files in the Java folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin files are typically placed in the `src/main/java` directory when using Android Studio. For instance, if you create a new Kotlin project using one of the provided templates on Android Studio (even on the latest version), the initial Kotlin files are created in the `src/main/java` directory. This may probably change in the future.

IntelliJ IDEA on the other hand places Kotlin files in the `src/main/kotlin` directory when developing a Kotlin project.